# how do the same calculation for every row with values of the same row: Zero Division Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, apply

I wanna have a function that runs through every row of my data frame and calculates a value in a column by using the values of other columns.

this is the dataframe:

```
  goal_value  ordered_value  proportion_of
0 20,67       5,34           0          
1 30,38       3,78           0
```

For example this is the code i m using rn:

```
def calculate_value(row):
    value1 = row[0]
    value2 = row[1]
    row[2] = value2/value1 * 100

dataframe.apply(calculate_value, axis = 'columns')
```

right now i get a ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Can someone pls help me.

Comment: aren't you getting error other than zero division error because you are trying to use `/` for string values

Answer (score 0):

this is all the code you need for this if I understand you correctly

```
df["proportion_of"] = df["ordered_value"] / df["goal_value"]
```

It is much faster than using apply given this is a vector operation, vs apply is a row-wise operation

Comment: Oh you right! Thanks a lot. New to python with pandas so need to learn a lot.